# EF Core Navigation Property is loaded although Query Filter is configured

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, global-query-filter

I use EF Core 5.0.4 with a MS SQL Server and Lazy Loading.
My entities all derive from `BaseEntity` which contains a `Deleted` property.
For all entities I configured a global query filter which allows to load only entities where `Deleted` is set to `false`.
Now I've got a `Project` entity and an `Appointment` entity and a n:m entity `ProjectAppointment`.

```
public class ProjectAppointment : BaseEntity
{
    public ProjectAppointment(Guid? id, Project project, Appointment appointment) : base(id)
    {
        Project = project;
        Appointment = appointment;
    }

    public ProjectAppointment(Guid? id, Guid projectId, Guid appointmentId) : base(id)
    {
        ProjectId = projectId;
        AppointmentId = appointmentId;
    }

    public ProjectAppointment()
    {
    }

    public Guid ProjectId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; private set; }
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; private set; }
}
```

All three types derive from `BaseEntity`.
If I load an appointment from database which contains a projectAppointment with was recently changed to `Deleted = true`, this navigation property will still be returned by ef core although the query filter should avoid this:

[image]

I created a [simplified repository](https://github.com/VILLAN3LL3/LazyLoadingFilterQuery) to demonstrate the issue. It also occurs without lazy loading.

How can I configure entity framework to not lazy load navigation properties with `Deleted = true`?

Comment: How it works without Lazy loading?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv unfortunately turning off the lazy loading mode is not an option for this project

Comment: I understand that. Just ensure that this works without Lazy Loading. If it works - create an issue in EF Core github repository. Otherwise, you have some problems in options configuration, which you have omitted from original question.

Comment: I'll create a small project to test this and will let you know about the results

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please find the link to the github repository in the original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have checked your sample.

You have loaded record, updated and trying to check that this records is not appears in other collection. Problem here that `ChangeTracker` already knows about this records and knows to which collection it should be applied even it is not returned from database.

Workarounds:

- ```
  _appContext.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Detached;
  ```
- ```
  _appContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
  ```
- Update in one `DbContext`, load in another.